# How can I make the `else` block only occur once in this code?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
vesi = ["Cody", "Dwight", "Jesse", "Justine", "Nneka", "Noelle"]
coco = ["Cassidy", "Geo", "James", "Karla", "Lindsay", "Ryan"]
baka = ["Elie", "Jeanine", "Mike", "Morriah", "Owen", "Sami"]

playername = input("Enter player name:")

if playername in vesi:
    print(f"{playername} is a member of the Vesi tribe.")
    break
else:
    print("Username is invalid or does not exist in the Vesi, Coco, or Baka tribe. Please try again.")
    break

if playername in coco:   
    print(f"{playername} is a member of the Coco tribe.")
    break
else:
    print("Username is invalid or does not exist in the Vesi, Coco, or Baka tribe. Please try again.")
    break
if playername in baka:
    print(f"{playername} is a member of the Baka tribe.")
    break
else:
    print("Username is invalid or does not exist in the Vesi, Coco, or Baka tribe. Please try again.")
    break
```

When I try this code, I get messages from both `if` and `else` blocks. For example:

```
Enter player name:Geo
Geo is a member of the Coco tribe.
Username is invalid or does not exist in the Vesi, Coco, or Baka tribe. Please try again.
```

After reading some other answers, I tried using `break`, but it does not seem to help. How can I make it so that the "Username is invalid" message only appears if the name is not in any of the tribes, and make it only appear once?

Comment: `break` is for breaking out of loops. You don't have a loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to fix the post to meet the standards described in [ask]. Please note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Questions should not talk about you, your level of experience, and *especially* not about how much you don't want the question to get downvoted. They should **only** contain a **question**. Focus on the code. Questions get downvoted because they don't meet the site standards - it is not a vote on you; it is a vote on the question.

Comment: "I did some [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" is not a reason people will like the question; **the question** should **demonstrate** the research. This means more than just looking up existing answers; it means attempting to understand the problem by [studying what the code does](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and trying to *isolate* the problematic part in a [mre].

Comment: It also means showing code that *works like you say it does* (if you got this result before adding `break`, then *don't show `break` in the code* - it is a syntax error here). Even aside from that, it's clear that you would get *three* output messages for any given name, not two. Make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** your code, **without changing anything**, run it as you describe, and get the **exact** result you describe. The best way to make sure of this is to try it yourself before hitting Submit.

Comment: Research *also* means attempting to learn the fundamentals by following a tutorial from start to finish, and paying attention. It is hard to imagine someone who can explain Python and show `if` and `else`, but not `elif`. (If you *have* seen `elif` before, then *think* about how it was explained, and how it might be relevant to the problem. Start by writing out, step by step, what should happen. (For beginners, I recommend using a real pencil and paper and writing out full English sentences, and/or drawing diagrams.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `elif` for a sequence of mutually exclusive conditions. The final `else:` will be used if none of them were true.

```
if playername in vesi:
    print(f"{playername} is a member of the Vesi tribe.")
elif playername in coco:   
    print(f"{playername} is a member of the Coco tribe.")
elif playername in baka:
    print(f"{playername} is a member of the Baka tribe.")
else:
    print("Username is invalid or does not exist in the Vesi, Coco, or Baka tribe. Please try again.")
```